# How to match the last occurrence of a pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given that I have the following string:

```
String 1 | string 2 | string 3
```

I want my regex to match the value after the last pipe and space, which in this case is "string 3".

Right now I am doing using this: `/[^|]+$/i` but it also return the space character after the pipe.

https://regex101.com/r/stnW0D/1

Comment: Use `s[/\s*([^|]*?)\s*\z/, 1]`. However, why not use `strip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'String 1 | string 2 | string 3'[/(?<=\|\s)(\w+\s\d+\z)/]
# "string 3"
```

Where (escaped):

```
\|  # a pipe
\s  # a whitespace
\w+ # one or more of any word character
\s  # a whitespace
\d+ # one or more digits
\z  # end of string

(...)    # capture everything enclosed
(?<=...) # a positive lookbehind
```

Notice in this case the regex is already getting the last occurrence of the pattern in the string, by attaching it to the end of the string (\z). In other case you could use `[\|\s]?` instead of (\|\s) to match the string followed by a whitespace and a number and from there, access the last element in the returned array:

```
'String 1 | string 2 | string 3'.scan(/[\|\s]?(\w+\s\d+)/).last
# ["string 3"]
```

Comment: Great answer Sebastian Palma. If the OP wants it as a string, he could do:
`'String 1 | string 2 | string 3'.scan(/\|\s(\w+\s\d+\z)/).map(&:first).join("', '")`

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
"String 1 | string 2 | string 3".split(" | ").last # => "string 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "string 1 | string 2 | string 3"

str[/[^ |][^|]*\z/]
  #=> "string 3"
```